# change dropdown value and pass it to the ajax on same page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I've following ajax function, I want value of the dropdown/select field need to passed in "mode" variable of auto suggest event.
following is jquery ajax:

```
$('#userType').on('change', function()
{
    alert( this.value ); // value="employess/freelancer"
});

$('#assigned_to, #assigned_to_search , #added_by_search').autosuggest({
    minLength:3,
    url:'ajaxSuggestive.php',
    valueParam:'name',
    showCode:false,
    data: {
        'mode':'employees'
    }
});
```

Comment: what is your problem here exactly ?

Comment: when I changed dropdown option from freelancer to employees. the value of select field is not able to access inside autosuggest ajax data field, i want to pass it as a "mode".

Answer (score 0):

Just access it in the definition:

```
$('#assigned_to, #assigned_to_search , #added_by_search').autosuggest({
    minLength:3,
    url:'ajaxSuggestive.php',
    valueParam:'name',
    showCode:false,
    data: {
        'mode': $('#userType').val()
    }
});
```

Comment: this will always return first selected value when page load. $('#userType').val()

Comment: bind to the select box's `change` event a function that will recreate the autosuggest, or if possible, one that will only update the 'data' attribute